# Ant build fails saying: package doesn't exist

Tags: ant, classpath, package

I get the followingn errors saying

[javac] C:.hudson\jobs\BR_BPM_App_v6.24\workspace\dependency\com\abcd
e\banking\dataobject\Relation.java:19: package org.apache.log4j does
not exist
[javac] import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

log4j-1.2.16.jar is present in classpath.
I get similar errors for other jars too

My task def is:

```
<target name="compile"  depends="prepare">
 <echo>   =====================================</echo>
 <echo>       Compiling Java source files      </echo>
 <echo>   =====================================</echo>     
 <javac srcdir="C:\.hudson\jobs\BR_BPM_App_v6.24\workspace\dependent_rt"      
   deprecation="on" debug="on" fork="yes" executable="C:/j2sdk1.4.2_08/bin/javac"
   compiler="javac1.4" memoryMaximumSize="1024m" memoryInitialSize="1024m" />
   <classpath refid="class.path.dir"/>
   <classes dir="${classes.dir}"/>
 </target>  

 <path id="class.path.dir">  
  <fileset dir="${libsrc}/CSP_JAR_DIR">  
     <include name="**/*.jar" />  
  </fileset>  
  <fileset dir="${libsrc}/CSP_JAR_DIR/compileonly_libs">  
     <include name="**/*.jar" />  
  </fileset>  
 </path>
```

Comment: I see you edited your post at Jan 31 deleting about everything ... why? Now the question is really useless.

Answer (score 0):

Define path **BEFORE** the `javac` target.